# PowerShell to Add XML Attribute to Variable

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file and would like to use PowerShell to search for the node based on a variable and then set the attribute as another variable which I can then use.

My XML is saved at C:\example.xml and the code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Portal>
<A23062013 Current="13" lastweek="12" />
<A24062013 Current="13" lastweek="12" />
</Portal>
```

The content of the XML nodes within the Portal node are actually dates in the format of ddMMyyy and these are prefixed with an A as above.

My Powershell code is below:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('ddMMyyyy')
$pre = "A"
$completedate = "$pre$date"
[xml] $file = get-content "C:\example.xml"
$xmlValuePrevious = $file.SelectNodes ('$completedate') | select lastweek
$xmlValueCurrent = $file.SelectNodes ('$completedate') | select Current
Write-Host "$xmlValuePrevious $xmlValueCurrent"
```

It currently throws up errors for lines 5 and 6 which say:

Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.

Probably something easy that I'm missing as I'm new to PS, but I've searched for ages and cant find anything specific about this issue.

Thanks, Ad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- Remove the space between `SelectNodes` and the opening parenthesis.
- Use double quotes if you want to expand variables inside a string. Or remove the quotes entirely if you want to pass only the variable.
- To select a node anywhere in the XML tree you need to prepend the node name with `//`. Using just the node name in an XPath expression will select only nodes with that name in the current node.

Change this:

```
$xmlValuePrevious = $file.SelectNodes ('$completedate') | select lastweek
$xmlValueCurrent = $file.SelectNodes ('$completedate') | select Current
```

into this:

```
$xmlValuePrevious = $file.SelectNodes("//$completedate") | select lastweek
$xmlValueCurrent = $file.SelectNodes("//$completedate") | select Current
```

Comment: Superb, thanks very much Ansgar, very much appreciated.
However, when I run it now the variables come back as @{lastweek=30} and @{Current=31}
am I able to change it so that all I get back is 30 and 31 please?

Comment: @ladders81 you should be able to select the values like this `$xmlValueCurrent.Current` (what you have there is a hashtable)

Comment: @ladders81 Expand the values of the properties: `... | select -Expand lastweek`

Answer (score 3):

Since Ansgar allready explained what the problem with your code is i wont go into that.

For accessing xml structures though you could also use the dot notation (which is a bit easier for beginners):

```
$xmlValuePrevious = $file.Portal.$completedate.lastweek
$xmlValueCurrent = $file.Portal.$completedate.current
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, 
When I run it now the variables come back as @{lastweek=30} and @{Current=31} am I able to change it so that all I get back is 30 and 31 please?

Comment: @ladders81 this should return the values directly and not a hashtable, what version of powershell are you on? also for the theory on accessing the values see my answer to your comment on ansgars post